# Package react-native-onesignal has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration

Tags: javascript, react-native, onesignal

I am trying to configure **OneSignal React Native** in a React Native application for push notification purposes.

Environment Setup

1. react-native version : 0.60
2. npm version 10.5

I followed the steps below from the [official documentation of React native one signal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup) for setting it up:

step 1 : `npm install -g react-native-cli`,
            status : done

step 2 : `react-native init OneSignalDemo`,
            status : done

Before linking the project I ran my project successfully with the commands below:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
react-native run-android
```

step 3: While linking my library with `react-native link react-native-onesignal` I got an error in my terminal.
Linking oneSignal with my App (As per official documentation),
              status : fail

**Error**:

```
Package react-native-onesignal has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. 
Reason: Unknown option dependency.platforms.ios.sourceDir with value ""./ios"" was found. 
This is either a typing error or a user mistake
```

One possible solution that I tried was to create new React Native project with version 0.58.0 as per [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup), but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What did you try already? We cannot help if you don't provide more details..

Comment: thank you this . i edit my question in details please have a look.

Comment: I don't know much about react, but judging by your error message, you have configured an `ios` directory somewhere, or that directory is present somewhere?

Comment: **$ rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules 
$ npm install** these two commands fixed my issue

Comment: @SBylemans Thank you for your valuable input,when we perform first two  steps it  will (React native) automatically create ios and adnroid directory in your project root folder

Answer (score 3):

i got the warn message but simple npm i solved the issue for me